# Suggested Edit accidentally merged with another edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I informed a user:

> Hi Ali, temporary comment to explain about [your suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15998602) that all occurrences of "thanks" on Stack Overflow should be removed, not added.

He replied:

> @Cœur, Yes actually I did not add it, it was there already but you are seeing it as added because someone has removed before my edit and I did not remove it.

So did I wrongly assumed that the addition of "Thanks" was from Ali786? How come we are seeing it as coming from him if it's not from him? How to avoid this incident of misinterpreting the author of a suggested edit?

Comment: Simple race condition. Opening the post to edit it gives you one version, and when you then submit it after someone else also edited, you get diffed against the new version.